# Can jquery.cookie handle objects as a value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, cookies

I would like to store a cookie object with multiple values associated with various keys. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie is the one I'm using, but I'm open minded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, you could serialize your object using JSON and then store the JSON.

Comment: Is there an obvious / easy way of doing that?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know json parse existed :D